# Sybase, last value for each interface on the where clause

Tags: sybase

every 5 minutes a data is writed to a DB, I need to get the last value of `t_in_bps`, `t_out_bps` for each `InfName`, this query will run every 5 minutes

I have tried with top 4 , I got the four interfaces (InfName) but not the latest value of each interface

```
SELECT TOP 4 TimeStamp, InfName, t_in_bps, t_out_bps
FROM eMetrics
WHERE InfName in ('Gi0/0/2', 'Gi0/0/1', 'Ethernet1/61', 'Ethernet1/17')
```

I tried with `top 4 max(TimeStamp)` and I got just only one interface.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `TimeStamp` is the same (or at least within a few seconds of each other) for the 4 records of interest, and previous `TimeStamp` values are several minutes old, you may get by with an `order by` clause:

```
SELECT TOP 4 TimeStamp, InfName, t_in_bps, t_out_bps
FROM eMetrics
WHERE InfName in ('Gi0/0/2', 'Gi0/0/1', 'Ethernet1/61', 'Ethernet1/17')
order by TimeStamp desc
```

Otherwise the normal solution would be to remove the `top 4` and use a correlated sub-query, eg:

```
SELECT e1.TimeStamp, e1.InfName, e1.t_in_bps, e1.t_out_bps
FROM   eMetrics e1
WHERE  e1.InfName in ('Gi0/0/2', 'Gi0/0/1', 'Ethernet1/61', 'Ethernet1/17')
and    e1.TimeStamp = (select max(e2.TimeStamp)
                       from   eMetrics e2
                       where  e2.InfName = e1.InfName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which sybase DB you are using -- suppose it's ASE -- the most popular Sybase DB now. You need a "having" statement to filter out the max timestamp record for each infname group --

```
select TimeStamp, InfName, t_in_bps, t_out_bps 
from eMetrics 
WHERE InfName in ('Gi0/0/2', 'Gi0/0/1', 'Ethernet1/61', 'Ethernet1/17') group by infname having TimeStamp=max(TimeStamp)
```

If you are using IQ or ASA -- it would be a watcom-sql syntax. But anyway -- using "having" can solve your problem.